# How to store possible attributes in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-associations

I have Question model , which has attributes "status" , "code" , "type" .

All three attributes should be a drop down , say status can be "active / closed/ inactive" and so on.

All possible options for these drop-down's should be from database. What is the best way to store this.

I planned to create new model say lookup which has

```
[lookup_for][lookup_type][lookup_value]
```

and link that model to questions with HABTM and create a joint table lookup_questions.

So that I can get all status to fill dropdown by querying lookup table like

```
@questions_status = lookup.find_by_lookup_type('status')
```

I am in right direction ?, i am not rails experienced, please advice me.

Comment: if the options of the dropdowns do not change very often I would prefer to put them into a configuration file like config/locales/en.yml. This avoids the extra roundtrips to the database. Putting such info into the database is kind of over-engineered imho ...

Comment: @awenkhh : It changes more often , i can't put in locales. Also there is another model "Answers" which has again type, that's why i added lookup_for field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I followed HABTM relationship.  I think that is the more right way for my app (since the lookups will keep on updating).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a model `Status`, `Code` and `Type` and store the values in their respective database tables in a value column. `User` model could look like this then

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :status
  has_one :code
  has_one :type
end
```

You can fill your drop-downs with `Status.all` for example.

Btw be careful with a `type` column in an ActiveRecord model. It is reserved for single table inheritance.

Comment: thanks for quick reply , here i need to create three new models. What if tomorrow i am adding new attribute say "question_code", then i need to create new model "code". Can you pls advise is the problem with my approach ?

Comment: Are you sure you are adding another attribute? If not it's a good approach to keep it simple and refactor later when you really need it.

Comment: Yes it will be added. Also more than one can be added , we can't keep creating new models for all.

Answer (score 0):

Putting simple status statii(?) in a database, let alone a HABTM may not be a good idea.  Only keep tables for data that will be user changed or may changed (semi) regularly.
To get things running just stick the options in your model, and if u see them changing a lot then add a table

In your model

```
STATUS = [
    #  Displayed       stored in db you can use integer or strings at per field.
    [ "Active",        1 ],
    [ "Closed",        2 ],
    [ "Inactive",      3 ]
```

In form(new/edit)

```
<%= f.select :question_status, 
              Question::STATUS,
              :prompt => "Select"  %>
```

In show

```
<%=h (Question::STATUS.find_all{|disp, value| value == @question.question_status}).map {|disp, value| disp} %>
```